# like and unlike system in php usin mysqli

Tags: php

I was trying to create a like/unlike button in php. My code works fine. I have a like button and when I click on it, it transfers data to my "likes" table in my database. My only problem is that when I click on a like button, I cannot auto change to unlike button. Any idea how to do this?

";
    $_SESSION['pid']=$row['id'];
    $userid=$_SESSION['userid'];
    echo $userid;
    ?>
    ">like

```
<?php
require '../connection/config.php';
$id=$_GET['id'];
$userid=$_SESSION['userid'];
$postid=$id;
{
$sql="select * from post inner join likenew on post.id=likenew.id where userid='$userid' and postid='$id'";
echo  $sql;
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if($row['status']=='')
{
$sql="insert into likenew(postid,userid) values('$id','$userid')";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
echo $sql;
}
if($result)
{
$sql="update likenew set status=1 where postid='$id' and userid='$userid'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
echo $sql;
}
elseif($row['status']=='1')
{
$sql="update likenew set status=0,status2='unlike' where postid='$id' and userid='$userid'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
echo $sql;
}
elseif($row['status']=='0')
{
$sql="update likenew set status=1,status2='like' where postid='$id' and userid='$userid'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
echo $sql;
}
}






/*if($result)
{
    header('location:likedisplay.php');
}
    else
    {
        echo "error";
    }
}


    if($num==1){

        $sql="insert into likenew(postid,userid) values('$id','$userid')";
        $result1=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
    }
    else
{
    $sql1="update likenew set status=1 where postid='$id' and userid='$userid'";

$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if($result)
{
    header('location:likedisplay.php');
}
    else
    {
        echo "error";
    }
}*/

?>
```

Comment: Use javascript or jQuery to change the button text and click function when the button is clicked.  Read about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_set.asp

Answer (score 0):

may be you can make it make it with javascript and the OnClick stuff ,,like:

`<input type='submit' name='like' OnClick='stuff()'>`

and then for the stuff  :

`<script>`
`function stuff(){`
`//change the button name here`
`}`
`</script>`